# R dot plot with custom dot size

Tags: r, graph

With the following data I want to create a dotplot of A,B,C, etc. on the y-axis and a,b,c, etc. on the x axis on R **where dot size is relative to the values.**

```
structure(list(Label = structure(1:9, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), A = c(3.74e-07, 
8.43e-06, 1.41e-07, 1.37e-07, 0.00345, 2.71e-05, 4.09e-06, 2.11e-05, 
0.0013), B = c(2.04e-07, 7.86e-07, 1.67e-08, 3.5e-08, 0.000501, 
1.71e-06, 3.74e-07, 2.76e-06, 0.00017), C = c(1.85e-09, 4.52e-05, 
1.85e-09, 3.05e-06, 0.0178, 0.00017, 9.23e-05, 0.000231, 0.0113
), D = c(1.46e-06, 4e-07, 1.1e-07, 1.85e-09, 0.000138, 3.14e-08, 
1.3e-07, 6.16e-07, 6.95e-05), E = c(3.26e-05, 2.43e-05, 2.17e-05, 
3e-06, 0.0021, 8.8e-06, 6.31e-06, 1.74e-05, 0.00139), F = c(3.62e-07, 
1.85e-09, 1.27e-07, 1.85e-09, 9.54e-05, 8.41e-07, 2.88e-07, 3.33e-06, 
3.74e-05), G = c(1.32e-07, 6.96e-06, 1.85e-07, 2.03e-07, 0.00262, 
1.74e-05, 1.29e-05, 2.93e-05, 0.00189)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Sort of like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you the show the `dput` of the example as it doesn't look like a correct format i.e. numbers as column names? followed by a row of strings and then numbers in the next rows?.  May be you need to use `skip` when reading the dataset to remove the first row, then read it separately

Comment: I have reformatted so the numbers for dot size are in row 2 and put the dput in the question

Comment: I think it is better if you show us what you have tried so far, I honestly can't understand your question or your data.

Comment: Does the same column names 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', etc needs to be addresseed

Comment: @akrun they are meant to be the same group, with all 'a' value dots in the same point on the x-axis

Comment: @Bruno at this point, I don't have anything because I'm not sure how to create a dot plot where it skips the first row

Comment: Ok so the column is the group, the value in each "cell" is y, and the first row is the size?

Comment: I apologize, I have misunderstood the data I was given. I will post a new question.

Comment: I apparently cannot create another question for 90 minutes, so I have edited my question. So sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: I still can't understand your question what is the observation(point), why 4 a's, 2 b's and 2 c's

Comment: @Bruno I apologize, each "a", "b", "c" are replicates (i.e. each a is a replicate of condition a), so I want one dot to represent the mean of the "a" values for each A, B, C, etc.

Comment: @Bruno I have transposed the data and found how to make a mean of the rows, so now I just need to figure out the graph. I have simplified my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but you probably should read about tidy data

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <-
  structure(
    list(
      Label = structure(
        1:6,
        .Label = c("A", "B", "C",
                   "D", "E", "F"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      a = c(0.9, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9,
            0.2, 0.4),
      a = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0),
      a = c(0.8, 0.4,
            0.8, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2),
      a = c(0.4, 0.7, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 1),
      b = c(1,
            0.2, 0.8, 0, 0.7, 0.8),
      b = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 0.7),
      c = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.7),
      c = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.1,
            0.8, 0.9, 0.7)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,
                  -6L)
  )

df1 <- df_example %>%
  pivot_longer(-Label, values_to = ".size", names_to = ".group") %>%
  group_by(Label, .group) %>%
  summarise(mean_size = .size %>% mean) %>%
  mutate(groupp = .group %>% as.factor())
#> Warning: Duplicate column names detected, adding .copy variable

p <- df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = groupp, y = Label, size = mean_size)) +
  geom_point()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me with the test data, however when I applied it to my real data, I got the error "Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object '.group' not found". Do you have any idea why this might be? The only difference I can think of is that my real data is very small (most values are around 10^-6)

Comment: Depends on the format of the data, can I see a dput of the head of your data

Comment: Keep in mind that I solved for your initial data, if you want to change the data it kind of defeats the answer, but still I should be able to quickly refactor it if necessary

Comment: Data is in the same format, but I have changed the dput to reflect real data

Comment: It appears to be working with a new R session. Apologies. Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it. I will revert my data to fake data for future users.

Comment: Please upvote and validate the answer it helps me to get more rights on SO, have a great day

Comment: Do you need me to delete my answer with real data?

Comment: I have upvoted the answer! Yes, please delete the answer with real data if you can. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a discrete scale (seen in the solution above), another possibility is to pivot_longer and set the value as size:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
pivot_longer(-Label) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=Label,y=name,size=value))
```

You can also plot it on log10 scale:

```
df %>% 
pivot_longer(-Label) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=Label,y=name,size=log10(value)))
```

[image]